# Send numerical data via TCP/IP ethernet

Tags: c++, c, winsock, fpga

So I know many of you will advise against this but I want to send floats via TCP/IP to a TCP Server running on a SoC (Zynq7020, with the server on the Arm A9). I want to get this working as a simple proof of concept before moving onto using UDP which is probably more suited to sending raw data. I am having trouble converting the float into a char array on the client side and back again on the server. Although I am not sure this is the best approach.

I am using  the WinSocket API, and am sending the data as so (although I am not sure this is correct or efficient!):

```
char * sendbuf;
sendbuf = reinterpret_cast<char *>(f);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int) strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

Basically is this correct, and without using UDP, what is the best way to floats via TCP. I guess decoding will essentially be reverse engineering the method used to send the float as char*.

---Below is a complete working example of sending floats via WinSock to a Zynq ARM cpu LwIP--

Host Windows 7 (htonf maybe used, but I am on x86 so there are no endian issues):

```
int FPGA_Accelerator::sendFloat(float* f) {
    char *sendbuf;
    int iResult;
    char arr[4];

    *(float*)arr= *f;

    printf("Sending "); printf(arr); printf("\n");
    iResult = send(connection, arr, (int) sizeof(arr), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(connection);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    return 1;
};
```

Zynq code. Where in the recv_callback I call the function `parse_input(p->payload)`

```
void parse_input(char* input){
    xil_printf("Input : ");
    xil_printf(input);
    xil_printf("\n\r");

u32 d = *(u32*)input;
union v{
    float f;
    u32 u;
};
union v val;
val.u = d;

printf("Value u32 = %i \n\r",val.u);
printf("Value float = %f \n\r",val.f);

}
```

Comment: «UDP which is probably more suited to sending raw data.» This is not true. UDP/TCP has nothing to do about rawness of data. In both cases, if you need to send the same float you'll have to use the same encoding :)

Comment: I would read a little about ASN.1, it might help if your data gets more complex

Comment: C ist not C++. They're not the same, still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question of TCP vs UDP.

First, to send a single float value, you don't reinterpret it as an address, but take the address of the float

```
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, &f, (int) sizeof(f), 0);
```

But this works only, if you have the same architecture on both ends of the communication.

To make it independent of architecture issues, you must use some [External Data Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) for the transmission from one system to another. Alternatively, you can also use a text based protocol and convert the float value to a string.

Comment: `htonf(f)` should be adequate for OP's case. I don't see much benefit in converting `f` to a string

Comment: Ths is wrong. `strlen(f)` makes no sense if `f` is a `float` or a pointer to a `float`.

Comment: @RedAlert, as you said I need to use htonf, but I am running Windows 7 and it is not in the WinSock API, (I cannot call the function, and on the WinSock API page it states that Windows 8 minimum is needed for htonf) are there any alternatives?

Comment: @SamPalmer You don't have to use `htonf` specifically. `htonl()` will convert any 32 bit input for you, so you can use that instead. Note that on the receiving end, you have to use `ntohl()` before you can consider it valid.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what you send is float or string. You send data as array of bytes and receive them on the other side and interpret them as you wish. So in your case, you should send a float which is 4 bytes long. You should send 4 bytes as array of bytes and on the other side cast it to a float and use it.

```
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)&f, (int) sizeof(float), 0);
```

in receiver part:

```
char *receivebuf;
// read data from socket
float *receivedFloat = (float*)receivebuf;
```

Using UDP is easier, because you don't have to check connection and success of sent data. You just send it without connecting to the server.

Answer (score -1):

This is incorrect. As its name suggests, `strlen` is for strings. You need to pass the actual size of the buffer to `send`.

Comment: the example (well the use of the send method, not the cast) I gave is correct and is a direct copy from the MSDN WinSocket example.